# Plotting DataFrame x,y,z (Pivot-Table) - Switch axis

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, matplotlib, pivot-table

I would like to plot the following DataFrame *df* as lines. So that I don't have to upload a file I have created an example array here. The zeros are replaced only NaN, so that they do not appear in the plot (Figure 1 - Plot). Unfortunately, changing the table with the commented out command did nothing. The plot remains the same.

Plot:

[image: Figure 1 - Plot]

I would like to swap the x and y axis as well as swap the order of the columns.  At the end it should look like the figure 2.

Result:

[image: Figure 2 - Result]

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

df = np.array([[1.984527906,    2.954823982,    3.929672499,    4.959261398,    5.99837202],
[1.990381781,   2.929568097,    3.95951958, 5.033245035,    5.989265035],
[1.957703504,   2.903082068,    3.940650489, 5.03420226,    6.099707906],
[2.000831255,   2.938274126,    4.000250298, 5.05252714,    6.057832594],
[1.967406661,   2.904963886,    4.101361781, 5.210597762,   6.073879772],
[1.974263791,   2.971977283,    4.159008097, 5.22840781, 6.074537953],
[2.028137225,3.163653014, 5.037366853, 0 ,0],
[2.034031388,3.242129474, 5.031475083, 0 ,0],
[0,0, 5.031525226, 0 ,0],
[0,0, 5.033628193, 0 ,0]])

df = pd.DataFrame(df, index=None).replace(0, np.NaN)

## Reshaping of the df wasn't successful.
# df = df[::-1][df.columns.tolist()[::-1]]
# df.columns = np.arange(0,df.shape[1],1)
# print(df)

fig, ax = plt.subplots(1,1)
df.plot(ax=ax)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### Swapping X and Y Variables in Matplotlib

It appears you want to change your dependent and independent variables here. This is an atypical way to plot data. Typically something like this would be done with a pivot table or dataframe transpose. But since you are using a continuous variable for the x_axis, this makes it a bit more difficult. I think plotting directly with matplotlib is going to be easier for this use case. Here is an example of how to implement this strategy.

I also reversed the plotting order as requested.

[image]

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(10,6))

for col in df.columns[::-1]:
    ax.plot(df.iloc[:, col], df.index, label=col)

#style chart
[ax.spines[s].set_visible(False) for s in ['top', 'right']]
ax.grid(axis='y', dashes=(8,3), color='gray', alpha = 0.7)
ax.tick_params(axis='both', bottom=False, left=False)
ax.set_ylim(0,9)
ax.legend(ncol=5, loc=(0.25,1.025), edgecolor='w')
```